# Video player package not detecting the duration in flutter

Tags: flutter, video-player, android-video-player

For some reason the video player package or any other available video player packages is not deducting the duration of the video with the network link. I have tried other link with my code and it works perfectly. I have a link which I get from 'Whereby - a video call platform' which has all the necessary metadata and other stuffs but this link doesn't deduct the duration

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(Uri.parse('url'));
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: (){
            _controller.seekTo(const Duration(seconds: 10));
            }, icon: const Icon(Icons.forward))
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (_controller.value.isPlaying) {
              _controller.pause();
            } else {
              _controller.play();
            }
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried with different packages, devices but it is not working. Since I don't get the duration I am not able to control the player like changing the video forward or backward or to specific duration.